# Analysing This Crash Report

Tags: ios, crash, report, segmentation-fault

I got this crash report, and I "symbolicated" it.
Even after that, I am still unable to understand where does my crash comes from.

The app crashes straight after launch.

Here's my crash report :

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Version:             1.6.0.3 (1.6.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-04-30 15:50:21.019 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-04-30 15:50:15.833 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193e056ac strlen + 12
1   App                             0x000000010012e1ec -[NSString(CategoryName) hashWithSecretKeyUpdateUser] (HashString.m:70)
2   App                             0x00000001000eff04 +[InAppPurchaseHelper generateSHAFromDictionary:registerOrReadOrUpdate:] (InAppPurchaseHelper.m:177)
3   App                             0x00000001000ef5b8 +[InAppPurchaseHelper updateUserInfosRegisterProfile:registerPush:] (InAppPurchaseHelper.m:119)
4   App                             0x0000000100166574 -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] (AppDelegate.m:218)
5   UIKit                           0x00000001869f7474 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 456
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181eda2c0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181eda72c ____CFXNotificationPostToken_block_invoke + 140
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181eec278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181eeb380 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 308
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ee99a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1752
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181e152d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018b62b6f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
13  UIKit                           0x00000001869dafa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484
14  App                             0x0000000100100ea4 main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000193dd6a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193ed4c24 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193db9e6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193dab998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48
```

Does this report means that the crash occured in the "hashWithSecretKeyUpdateUser" function call ?

Is there a way to know more about the crash ?

I wasn't able to get my App to crash at this point

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Segmentation fault"(SIGSEGV) which means your code accessing the memory that doesn't exist or invalid. According to your crash report, it looks like hashWithSecretKeyUpdateUser accessing wrong or invalid memory from "strlen + 12" which I believe string you are passing into hashWithSecretKeyUpdateUser is not exist or fault.